# how to display datagridview in another tabs (tabcontrol) in vbnet

Tags: sql, visual-studio, datagridview, tabcontrol

i hope someone could help me. I have a project in vbnet which linked to database. My lecturer asked me to use tabcontrol. I have done all source codes in tabpages1 and i got difficulty in the next process. I have to write the procedure in tabpage2 to search data from datagrid(dgv1) by input some key and it must be shown in tabpages2(using dgv2). it something like i have to call dgv1 in tabpages2(with dgv2) i included the source code which i have done so far. due date is 1 week and i hope i could solve it immediately.( so sorry its mixed with bahasa ) thank you

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form2
    Public cmd As MySqlCommand
    Public rd As MySqlDataReader
    Public da As MySqlDataAdapter
    Public ds As DataSet
    Public SQL As String

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet

        Call conecDB()
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("Select kd_pemasok ,nm_pemasok,cp,alamat_pemasok,telp_pemasok FROM tb_pemasok", connDB)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "tb_pemasok")
        dgv1.DataSource = ds.Tables("tb_pemasok")
        dgv1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Kode Pemasok"
        dgv1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Nama Perusahaan"
        dgv1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Contact Person"
        dgv1.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Alamat Perusahaan"
        dgv1.Columns(4).HeaderText = "Telp Perusahaan"
    End Sub
    Private Sub TabPage1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabPage1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnsimpan_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsimpan.Click
        Try

            SQL = "INSERT INTO `tb_pemasok`(`kd_pemasok`, `nm_pemasok`, `cp`, `alamat_pemasok`, `telp_pemasok`) " _
                & "VALUES ('" & txtkd_pemasok.Text & "','" & txtnm_pemasok.Text & "','" & txtcp.Text & "','" & txtalamat.Text & "','" & txttelp.Text & "')"

            cmd = New MySqlCommand(SQL, connDB)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MessageBox.Show("Insert Data Barang Berhasil")

            da = New MySqlDataAdapter("Select kd_pemasok ,nm_pemasok,cp,alamat_pemasok,telp_pemasok FROM tb_pemasok", connDB)
            ds = New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds, "tb_pemasok")

            dgv1.DataSource = ds.Tables("tb_pemasok")
            txtkd_pemasok.Text = ""
            txtnm_pemasok.Text = ""
            txtcp.Text = ""
            txtalamat.Text = ""
            txttelp.Text = ""
            txtkd_pemasok.Focus()


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Insert data Barang GAGAL.")
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub dgv1_CellMouseClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dgv1.CellMouseClick
        lbkd_pemasok.Text = dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value

        txtkd_pemasok.Text = dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
        txtnm_pemasok.Text = dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value
        txtcp.Text = dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value
        txtalamat.Text = dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value
        txttelp.Text = dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Value

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnedit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnedit.Click

        If txtkd_pemasok.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("SILAHKAN KLIK SALAH SATU DATA DARI GRID BARANG UNTUK EDIT DATA")
            dgv1.Focus()
        Else
            If btnedit.Text = "Edit" Then
                btnedit.Text = "Update"
                btnsimpan.Enabled = False
                txtkd_pemasok.Enabled = True

                txtkd_pemasok.Focus()
            Else
                Try

                    SQL = "UPDATE `tb_pemasok` SET `kd_pemasok`='" & txtkd_pemasok.Text & "'," _
                    & "`nm_pemasok`='" & txtnm_pemasok.Text & "'," _
                    & "`cp`='" & txtcp.Text & "'," _
                    & "`alamat_pemasok`='" & txtalamat.Text & "'," _
                    & "`telp_pemasok`='" & txttelp.Text & "' " _
                    & "WHERE `kd_pemasok`='" & lbkd_pemasok.Text & "'"
                    cmd = New MySqlCommand(SQL, connDB)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    MessageBox.Show("UPDATE Data Barang Berhasil")
                    da = New MySqlDataAdapter("Select kd_pemasok ,nm_pemasok,cp,alamat_pemasok,telp_pemasok FROM tb_pemasok", connDB)
                    ds = New DataSet
                    da.Fill(ds, "tb_pemasok")

                    dgv1.DataSource = ds.Tables("tb_pemasok")

                    txtkd_pemasok.Text = ""
                    txtnm_pemasok.Text = ""
                    txtcp.Text = ""
                    txtalamat.Text = ""
                    txttelp.Text = ""

                    txtkd_pemasok.Enabled = True
                    btnsimpan.Enabled = True
                    btnedit.Text = "Edit"


                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("UPDATE Data Barang GAGAL")

                End Try
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnhapus_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnhapus.Click
        If txtkd_pemasok.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("SILAHKAN KLIK SALAH SATU DATA DARI GRID BARANG UNTUK DIHAPUS")
            dgv1.Focus()
        Else
            Try
                SQL = "delete from tb_pemasok where `kd_pemasok`='" & txtkd_pemasok.Text & "'"
                cmd = New MySqlCommand(SQL, connDB)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                da = New MySqlDataAdapter("Select kd_pemasok ,nm_pemasok,cp,alamat_pemasok,telp_pemasok FROM tb_pemasok", connDB)
                ds = New DataSet
                da.Fill(ds, "tb_pemasok")
                txtkd_pemasok.Text = ""
                txtnm_pemasok.Text = ""
                txtcp.Text = ""
                txtalamat.Text = ""
                txttelp.Text = ""

                txtkd_pemasok.Enabled = True
                btnsimpan.Enabled = True
                btnedit.Text = "Edit"

                dgv1.DataSource = ds.Tables("tb_pemasok")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("HAPUS Data Barang GAGAL")

            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnkelur_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnkelur.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btncari_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btncari.Click
        If txtcarinama.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Silahkan Masukkan Nama Pemasok", MsgBoxStyle.Question, "Pertanyaan")
            txtcarinama.Focus()
        Else
            da = New MySqlDataAdapter("Select kd_pemasok,nm_pemasok,cp,alamat_pemasok,telp_pemasok from tb_pemasok where nm_pemasok='" & txtcarinama.Text & "'", connDB)
            ds = New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds, "tb_pemasok")
            dgv2.DataSource = ds.Tables("tb_pemasok")
        End If
       
    End Sub

End Class
```

[image]

Comment: You never state what the problem is. It looks like the second Tab Page HAS a `DataGridView` so it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I have datagridview1 in tabpage1 and I have a search button in tabpage2 which taken data frm datagridview1. I can pass the data from datagrid1 to datagrid2(tabpages2) but searching procedure couldnt be processed. how to solve it? thanks in advance

Comment: You commented that… _“… searching procedure couldnt be processed. … “_ ? “Why” couldn’t it be processed? Is there an error? Nothing happens? In other words what is happening and what are you expecting to happen. I am guessing that the last code snippet… `btncari_Click` is the button click event for the button shown in the picture (please correct me if this is not the case). So when you click on the button… what happens? Put a breakpoint on the first line of that method and trace what happens.